# Regex to identify username across multiple sites

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex to identify username across multiple sites.

There are multiple sites that may be the domain name, which I may add more down the road.

From there, I am looking for a @xxxxxxx either directly after domain/ or after domain/tag/@xxxxxxxx.  There may be an unknown number of characters after the username and sometimes there may be a / and unknown content after that I am not concerned with.

I am basically looking through a list of domains with/without http/https, then look at the first or second position for a @alphanumeric until next / or empty.

Example urls:

```
https://site1.com/@bob
https://site2.com/boats/@frank/how-to-fix-your-boat
http://site2.com/@frank/settings
site1.com/@joe.beans/re-how-to-fix-your-boat-248435252
```

I am looking at identifying the @username from each type of url that might show up.

I will maintain a list of domains being searched, some may be added down the road.  I will be using JS to iterate the list and fill in that part of the regex.

I believe regex will be the fastest way to do this unless there is something else that would be available a chrome extension that would be easier.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the Javascript code you have already written and tell us how it does not do what you need.

Comment: I have not written any js yet, I was starting the regex to reliably capture the username.

Comment: If you don't have Javascript code, then [edit] your post and add the regular expression you already have. Please also show us examples of what you intend your regex to match, and what you intend to not match, and also tell us where the regex goes wrong. As a side note, this is not a program writing service, so we expect most of the work to be done by you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex `/(.+)\/@([^\/\r\n]+)/` to capture both the site and username like so:

```
var re = /(.+)\/@([^\/\r\n]+)/;
var match = re.exec(url);
if (match != null) {
    site = match[1];
    user = match[2];
}
```

Using your examples:

> ```
> 'https://site1.com/@bob'                                  --> site = "https://site1.com";       user = "bob"
> 'https://site2.com/boats/@frank/how-to-fix-your-boat'     --> site = "https://site2.com/boats"; user = "frank"
> 'http://site2.com/@frank/settings'                        --> site = "http://site2.com";        user = "frank"
> 'site1.com/@joe.beans/re-how-to-fix-your-boat-248435252'  --> site = "site1.com";               user = "joe.beans"
> ```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to capture the protocol, the domain and the user, then this should do it:

```
var re = /^((?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^@\/\r\n]+)?(?:\/.+)?\/@([^\/\r\n]+)/;
var match = re.exec(url);
if (match != null) {
    protocol = match[1];
    domain   = match[2];
    user     = match[3];
}
```

This will yield:

> ```
> url                                                         match[1]  match[2]   match[3]
> ---                                                         --------  --------   --------
> https://site1.com/@bob                                  --> https://  site1.com  bob
> https://site2.com/boats/@frank/how-to-fix-your-boat     --> https://  site2.com  frank
> http://site2.com/@frank/settings                        --> http://   site2.com  frank
> site1.com/@joe.beans/re-how-to-fix-your-boat-248435252  -->           site1.com  joe.beans
> ```

**Regex Details**

```
"^" +                Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator)
"(" +                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   "(?:" +           Match the regular expression below
                     Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
         "http" +    Match the character string “http” literally (case insensitive)
      "|" +
                     Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
         "ftp" +     Match the character string “ftp” literally (case insensitive)
   ")" +
   "s" +             Match the character “s” literally (case insensitive)
      "?" +          Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ":" +             Match the character “:” literally
   "\\/" +           Match the character “/” literally
   "\\/" +           Match the character “/” literally
")" +
   "?" +             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"(?:" +              Match the regular expression below
   "www" +           Match the character string “www” literally (case insensitive)
   "\\." +           Match the character “.” literally
")" +
   "?" +             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"(" +                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   "[^" +            Match any single character NOT present in the list below
      "@" +          The literal character “@”
      "\\/" +        The literal character “/”
      "\r" +         The carriage return character
      "\n" +         The line feed character
   "]" +
      "+" +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")" +
   "?" +             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"(?:" +              Match the regular expression below
   "/" +             Match the character “/” literally
   "." +             Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator)
      "+" +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")" +
   "?" +             Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"/@" +               Match the character string “/@” literally
"(" +                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   "[^" +            Match any single character NOT present in the list below
      "\\/" +        The literal character “/”
      "\r" +         The carriage return character
      "\n" +         The line feed character
   "]" +
      "+" +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
")"
```

Comment: @Cid Well, that was not the question, but it's easy to expand the regex to `var re = /(https?:\/\/)(.+)\/@([^\/\r\n]+)/;` Then, after the exec, `scheme = match[1];`, `site = match[2];` and `user = match[3];`. Mind that for the last example url, the value for `scheme` will be empty.

Comment: @Cid Ah, I'm sorry I misunderstood. I see I did a wrong copy/paste in the example output. I have corrected that now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: wow, that's compact.  Need to digest how it works, and try to see if I can get the protocol separated so I can compare just the domain.  This gets me on the right track, thanks!

Comment: Ok, this is what I have:

    ^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\/\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?\n]+)\/.*@([^\/\r\n]+)


It captures the domain and the user.

Comment: @Michael If by protocol you mean 'http://' or 'https://' just put the regex in I have mistakenly commented to Cid. In that comment I named it `scheme`. Cheers

Comment: @Michael I have just added more code to my answer. Hope that helps